# Can not find other kernel when start jupyter with a custom config

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I copy the default config`jupyter_notebook_config.py` and change it IP setting as my custom config。
after I run jupyter with

```sh
jupyter-notebook -config custom.py
```

I can not find other kernel in the jupyter kernel list。
but when I start jupyter with default config:

```sh
jupyter-notebook
```

I can find all kernel....
I dont know whats wrong with my custom setting?

Comment: can you try with changing `-config` to `--config-dir` and provide directory path of `custom.py`.

Comment: It raise a error:`[C 15:02:21.547 NotebookApp] Unrecognized flag: '--config-dir'
`      
there is no `--config-dir` in jupyter params list

Comment: what version of jupyter you are using?

Comment: ```
jupyter core     : 4.5.0
jupyter-notebook : 5.7.8
qtconsole        : 4.5.1
ipython          : 7.6.0
ipykernel        : 5.1.1
jupyter client   : 5.2.4
jupyter lab      : not installed
nbconvert        : 5.5.0
ipywidgets       : 7.4.2
nbformat         : 4.4.0
traitlets        : 4.3.2
```